# Get all documents with specific nested field value, sans one document

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I have a table `videos` with documents that look like this:

```json
{
     "title":"Video Name",
     "description": "A description",
     "slug":"video-name",
     "studio": {
         "name": "Studio Name",
         "uid":"zyxwvut"
     },
     "uid":"abcdefghijkl"
}
```

I'm trying to grab related videos by the current video's studio by getting all videos with the `studio.uid` of `zyxwvut`, while also removing the ID of the requested video (`uid` of `abcdefghijkl`).

I've tried a few queries:

```
r.db('dev').table('videos').filter(function(video){ return video('studio')('uid').contains('zyxwvut').and(r.not(video('uid').eq("abcdefghijkl"))) })
```

with `r.js`:

```
r.db('dev').table('videos').filter(function(video){ return r.('(function (video) { return video.studio.uid == "zyxwvut"; })').and(r.not(video('uid').eq("abcdefghijkl"))) })
```

Am I going about this all wrong, or is it not possible?

Comment: On top of neumino's answer, I also found out that I could create a secondary index based on the nest field, then just use that with a `getAll()` and filter out the current video ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You can do:

```
r.db('dev').table('videos').filter(function(video) {
  return video("studio")("uid").eq("zyxwvut")
})
```

Comment: Wow. If it were a snake... Thank you very much!